# Is it possible to disable spring batch's skip-limit?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

I am looking for a way to disable spring batch's skip-limit, I tried specifying a value of "0" for skip-limit, but is not accepting. Here is my use case:

My `batch.xml` has `skip-limit="${limit_val}"`

I want to set `${limit_val}` to 0, meaning fail on any exception by default. On seeing the failure, I can look at the reason and decide if its ok to skip the record. If skippable, I want to be able to override `${limit_val}` with a value of, say 1 and re-run the batch.

Any help on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Write a processor and check if item il elegible to move forward in processing pipeline or skip it (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#filiteringRecords)

Comment: The decision to skip had to be manual here, hence the need to "fail-on-any-error"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using skip-policy property?
In chunk under step define skip-policy="mySkipPolicy" and then give definition of skipPolicy bean.

Provide skipPolicy bean implementation by implementing SkipPolicy Interface.

```
    public class MySkipPolicy implements SkipPolicy
    {
    private int limit;
    public boolean shouldSkip(final Throwable t, final int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException
    {
    return true or false based on skipCount;

    }
    }
```